# Strange treatment of "plus" character (+) by Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer

This is really weird... When I open the following simple HTML document in Internet Explorer 7.0.5730.11 (on Windows Server 2003 Web Edition SP2)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>+</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

it shows me a totally blank page. FWIW, this is just a trivial "repro" sample. In real HTML documents, I observed other, even more bizzarre effects caused by presense of the "plus" character that follows a tag.

**NB:** The problem appears to be extremely ittermittent. Most of the time it does work properly (i.e. displays the "plus" character), and I still can't find any way to reproduce this problem at will.

Some additional details based on recent comments:

- There was no server involved. I was opening a file on disk (i.e. used **file://** protocol).
- The file did not contain anything except five lines shown above. No document type declarations, no character encodings, no nothings.

Looks like a bug in IE. Did anybody encounter the same or similar problem?

**NB:** I appreciate all the responses received so far, but neither of respondednts encountered this problem. Something tells me that 99.(9)% of StackOverflow audience will not be able to reproduce it. :-)

Comment: Works fine in 7.0.5730.13 loaded from a file.

Comment: Maybe you are seeing a cached page.

Comment: What character encoding are you using by default?

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm not sure. I didn't specify any encoding explicitly. The sample code shown above is all that was there in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you use the numeric character reference notation?

```
<html>
  <body>
     <p>&#43;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use a Doctype? IE does get a bit picky if you don't use a doctype (insert no-right-to-be-picky pun here).

By intermittent do you mean using the same code it appears and doesn't? That sounds *really* strange.

*CLOSED - NOT REPRO*... er I mean I only get the +, no matter how many times I refresh. I suggest using the HTML entity reference - but this might be a problem with your system/browser if others can't reproduce either.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean by "intermittent"...

And today it is totally unreproducable on my system. Yes, it does look like some problem with my system/browser.

Comment: Sorry, can't try your idea about DOCTYPE right now... Will try as soon as the bug rears its stinky head again.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it's worth, I just tested this on IE 7 (7.0.5730.13C0) and it consistently displays the "+" even with several refreshes (at least 10 or 12).  You didn't mention an OS but in my case it's Windows XP SP2 (Help About displays Version 5.1 (Build 2600.xpsp_sp2_qfe.070227-2300: Service Pack 2).  The OS may make a difference in this case.

Comment: True. :-( FWIW, I have Windows Server 2003 Web Edition SP2.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this is due to the server, particularly if it's trying to parse the page as a script.  To check:

- What HTTP headers do you see when the effect occurs?
- When you "View Source" at that point, what do you see?
- Does the effect ever occur when you load the page directly as a file?
- Does the effect ever occur in other browsers?

Comment: There was no server involved: I was opening an HTML file on a disk (i.e. using **file://** protocol). "View Source" shows exactly the right source. I did not try any other browsers.